# OpenImaj - recognize given face which is not taken from the face database

Tags: face-recognition, openimaj

The OpenImaj Tutorial for face analysis shows how to do face recognition using some test images from the face database - http://openimaj.org/tutorial/eigenfaces.html

How a new given image which is not from the face db can be recognized? Can you give an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple - just modify the code in the tutorial so that instead of looping over all the faces in the database, it just takes in an image you specify and searches with that:

```
    FImage face = ...; //you load the face you want to search with here
    DoubleFV testFeature = eigen.extractFeature(face);

    String bestPerson = null;
    double minDistance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (final String person : features.keySet()) {
        for (final DoubleFV fv : features.get(person)) {
            double distance = fv.compare(testFeature, DoubleFVComparison.EUCLIDEAN);

            if (distance < minDistance) {
                minDistance = distance;
                bestPerson = person;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Best Guess: " + bestPerson);
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you also give a sample how to initialize the features map?

Comment: Also should I perform any training?

Comment: Oh, my bad - I was confused with the training and testing images.. Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/openimaj/openimaj/issues/344